# State budget spending of Roman Empire

Tags: roman-empire, finance

What can be said about the state budget (aerarium + fiscus + a.militare + etc) spending of the Roman Empire at the time of Augustus, say 14 A.D.?  Can it be estimated in sesterces?

Answer (score 1):

One caveat to trying to do this would be that Rome didn't exactly operate a modern capitalist society. For example, all the excess grain harvested in North Africa (including the Nile valley) was simply put on ships and given out to the public in Rome.

Comment: I am okay with estimates in pounds of grain, liters of oil and ounces of gold.

Comment: Another thing to note was that often times, soldiers (and probably other people) weren't paid in money(like sesterces), many times they were paid in salt because it was so valuable at the time.

Comment: It would suck if they were paid in salt when it was raining...

Comment: The wikipedia article on Roman empire has an estimate of GDP in sesterces and wheat equivalent, btw.

Comment: on Roman economy, I mean, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_economy